# Prevent web apps from using browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps, webapp-development

So I've been "developing" web apps for Ubuntu mobile devices using the [Web App Generator](http://developer.ubuntu.com/webapp-generator/) and all seems to be going well... But some - not all - of my web apps move over to the browser when a link is clicked.

Is it possible to *prevent* web apps from opening their content in the browser, and *force* them to stay within the web app itself?

Am I missing something - is there some way I can do this *within* the [Web App Generator](http://developer.ubuntu.com/webapp-generator/)? Or perhaps by *manually* editing one of the files inside the web app setup (".click") file?

Comment: Anyone? No suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while ago with a Web App being pinned to the Home screen of an iOS device.

The issue was related to the way the App treated links. i.e. if there is a link we need to open it in a webs browser

I'm unsure if the code will work in your situation as I have not used the Web App Generator to test but here it is.

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    a[i].onclick=function()
    {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false
    }
}
```

StackOverflow link for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window

Comment: I extracted the ".click" package and had a look through the files contained therein using gedit... But I couldn't find the code you talk about, or anything that looked similar.

Comment: From what I can tell you are trying to create an app by wrapping a website in a browser. If so you need to add this code to the website as Javascript